# 'remote move' via FTPS

Tags: ftp

I'm using **FTPS** to transfer some files from one remote server to another. 
Now would I like to move files locally on one server, from one folder to another. More concrete: after moving the files from [remote server 1] to [remote server 2] I want to move all the files with extension .csv to the folder done.
I found the 'rename' command but there is no 'rename all' function like:

```
rename *.csv ../done/*.csv
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an SSH access to the machine? That would make it much easier.

Comment: yes sure, sort of! It's a win2008 machine which I have remote access to

Answer (score 1):

Using `*` as a wildcard like you're doing is known as globbing. Globbing is often only available for local files through FTP, not remote ones. Some clients do glob remote FTP commands but, generally only the m* ones (mdelete, mget etc.)

Have a look at your clients `glob` command.

Also, globbing the way you asked in the question won't work, it would be:

```
rename *.csv ../done
```

I have a feeling you'll need to script it or do it manually because FTP is suited to that, not hand moving stuff around.

Comment: I'd hoped... But this command failed